# RecyclerView inside MotionLayout :Error processing scroll; pointer index for id -1 not found. Did any MotionEvents get skipped?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-motionlayout

I have a motionlayout with vertical recyclerview inside. Transition triggers on swipe on recyclerview:

```
   <OnSwipe
                app:dragDirection="dragUp"
                app:moveWhenScrollAtTop="true"
                app:touchAnchorId="@+id/fragment_restaurant_details_menu_list"
                app:touchAnchorSide="top"
                app:touchRegionId="@+id/fragment_restaurant_details_menu_list" />
```

This RecyclerView attached to the view above(inside motion layout). So when im starting to scroll recyclerview, view above should collapse(with motion layout transition) and recyclerview should get higher.

But when im touching recycleriew and making a "micro swipe" transition instantly getting to the end state without animation.

Logs :

```
E/RecyclerView: Error processing scroll; pointer index for id -1 not found. Did any MotionEvents get skipped?
```

Comment: did you solve it? any directions you went through?